# Alert Message is not Displaying Properly

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I want to display the below message in French Language

eg: `Rack(s) [...]ne peut pas être déclaré HS.`

but i am getting `Rack(s) [...] ne peut pas e darHS .`

here some of the character is not displaying like `écl`, `é`.

I am using alert Tag to display message .

I already used unicode character in message.properties file.

below is my code .please help

```
else if (screenName.equals(...)) {
    return "Rack [" + ErrorMessage + "] " + getResourceValue("message.info.popup.rackscrap", locale);
```

and in message .properties i used

```
message.info.popup.rackscrap= ne peut pas être d\u00e9clar\u00e9 HS`
```

and i am using AJAX call to display message

```
var error = item.error;
if(error!="")
    alert('ERROR ' + error);
```

Message is not displaying in alert showing some garbage letter or not dislaying special character like é,l',..

Comment: The html you have uses which encoding? If it is iso-8859-1 rendering utf-8 will cause strange characters

Comment: @Jan: i used UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Can you share the controller code sending you the data? Somewhere the content-type / charset gets mangled

Answer (score 0):

It will helpful if you share the ajax controller code.

I had a similar problem and I solved it by assigning the charset in the response.

See below source code:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```